# Replace the same occurances by multiple strings

Tags: vector, replace

Let's say I have a vector with multiple strings:

```
a<- c('a?cd','ab?cd','abc?')
```

How can I replace the first "?" by b the second "?" by c and the third "?" by d, in order to produce a result like this:

```
'abcd','abcd','abcd'
```

---

Improving the topic with the answer from G. Grothendieck!

In case we have two symbols in the same element that should be replaced by different patterns:

```
a <- c('espa?a','per? an?n','peque?os')
L <- c('N','U','O','N'); 
fmt <- gsub("[?]", "%s", a)
g <- cumsum(sequence(nchar(gsub("[^?]", "", a)))==1)
mapply(function(fmt, x) do.call("sprintf", as.list(c(fmt, x))), fmt, split( L, g), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

Comment: Then wouldn't the second one be `abccd`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `chartr` across each component as follows.  Note that `head(...)` is `c("b", "c", "d")` .  No packages are used.

```
a<- c('a?cd','ab?cd','abc?') # test input
mapply(chartr, "?", head(letters[-1], length(a)), a, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
## [1] "abcd"  "abccd" "abcd"
```

If what you meant was to check if any elements of "a", "b", "c", "d" are missing from each component and if so then replace ? with that missing element then first create a list of L of replacements and then apply `sub` to each component with it.  We assume that there are 0 or 1 missing elements from each component and 0 or 1 instances of ? in each component. Again, no packages are used.

```
L <- lapply(strsplit(a, ""), setdiff, x = letters[1:4])
L[lengths(L) == 0] <- ""
mapply(`sub`, "[?]", L, a, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
## [1] "abcd" "abcd" "abcd"
```

Comment: any idea on how to replace the same pattern by different strings:
a<-c('espa?a','per? an?n','peque?os')
L<-list('N','U','O','N')
mapply(`sub`, "[?]", L, to_fix, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
like in this case?

Comment: `a <- c('espa?a','per? an?n','peque?os');
L <- c('N','U','O','N');
fmt <- gsub("[?]", "%s", a);
g <- cumsum(sequence(nchar(gsub("[^?]", "", a)))==1);
mapply(function(fmt, x) do.call("sprintf", as.list(c(fmt, x))), fmt, split( L, g), USE.NAMES = FALSE)`

Comment: absolutely helpful. Thanks G. Grothendieck!

Answer (score 2):

`stringr::str_replace()` has vectorized replacement so you can do:

```
library(stringr)

str_replace(a, "\\?", letters[seq_along(a) + 1])

[1] "abcd"  "abccd" "abcd"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_replace` from `stringr`package

```
library(stringr)
a<- c('a?cd','ab?cd','abc?') 
str_replace(a,"[?]",letters[2:4])

[1] "abcd"  "abccd" "abcd"
```

or

```
str_replace(a, "[?]",  c("b", "c", "d"))

[1] "abcd"  "abccd" "abcd"
```

Comment: Does this add anything to the solution by "27 ϕ 9"